# My head hurts - 2 separate lights & 2 separate switches affecting each other

Tags: electrical

Update on dining room wiring! With pics! Here’s hoping some one can help me out!
A - switch with source line and line to light (B)
B - light with wire connecting to second light (C)
C - 2nd light (was ceiling fan without light) with clipped off wire and wire to switch (D)
D - single pole switch for 2nd light -C

Situation:
Switch A turns on light B and turns off light C (if it was on, if it was off it did nothing)
Switch D, if switch A was off, would turn on/off 2nd light C
- if switch A was on switch D did nothing

I hope that makes sense and now enjoy my pic skills

I have a situation in my dining room. It’s long so one side is the dining room light and the other end has a ceiling fan. Both have their own single switches. If the ceiling fan is turned on and running, and I turn on the dining room light the ceiling fan turns off. And vice versa. The incoming power goes thru the dining switch up to the dining room light over to the ceiling fan and then down to the fan switch. Any clue how I would fix that? [image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Yes, you [edit] your question to include photographs of the interior of all switch boxes and the lamp boxes, and a more precise description including which photo is which.  We solve these kinds of things all the time, but we need that much information to do it.   The switches need to be pulled aside, but not disconnected.  Do this with the power breakers off.

Comment: Awesome! I’ll do that now.

Comment: Has anyone changed any wiring lately,  changed any switches?

Comment: Yes, photos of the interiors of all boxes are quite helpful

Comment: None of the wiring has been changed. Also do I just post pics of the outlet boxes?

Comment: @Tonkadog turn the breaker off, undo the faceplates, unmount and pull out (but do *not* unwire) the switches and lights, and post photos of the insides of said junction boxes please.

Comment: Ok I’ve updated my post with pictures and a better description.

Comment: @Tonkadog how do you want this to behave?

Comment: @Tonkadog also, what kind of lightbulbs are you using here?

Comment: I wish I could add a pic here. I want switch A to control light B and switch D to control light C

Comment: @Tonkadog -- btw, it seems that you posted the same question twice, so I closed this as a duplicate of your other question.  Let me know if that's not correct, k?